# Save a large Spark Dataframe as a single json file in S3

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Im trying to save a Spark DataFrame (of more than 20G) to a single json file in Amazon S3, my code to save the dataframe is like this :

```
dataframe.repartition(1).save("s3n://mybucket/testfile","json")
```

But im getting an error from S3 "Your proposed upload exceeds the maximum allowed size", i know that the maximum file size allowed by Amazon is 5GB.

Is it possible to use S3 multipart upload with Spark? or there is another way to solve this?

Btw i need the data in a single file because another user is going to download it after.

*Im using apache spark 1.3.1 in a 3-node cluster created with the spark-ec2 script.

Thanks a lot

JG

Comment: I just saw that if i use s3a instead of s3n it could solve my problem (http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3) , but the thing is that the hadoop version that im using (Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.2.0) it does not support s3a. Any ideas? Thanks again.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I would try separating the large dataframe into a series of smaller dataframes that you then append into the same file in the target.

```
df.write.mode('append').json(yourtargetpath)
```

Comment: @TheRandomSuite: By any chance, do you know if it is possible to avoid the hadoopish format and store data to a file under a s3 key name of my choice instead of the directory with `_SUCCES` and `part-*` ?

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
dataframe.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.json").mode(SaveMode.Append).save("hdfs://localhost:9000/sampletext.txt");
```

Answer (score -5):

s3a is not production version in Spark I think. 
I would say the design is not sound. repartition(1) is going to be terrible (what you are telling spark is to merge all partitions to a single one). 
I would suggest to convince the downstream to download contents from a folder rather than  a single file