# Saving JSON in scala from SparkSQL

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark SQL for extracting some information from a JSON file. The question is I want to save the result from the SQL analysis into another JSON for plotting it with Plateau or with d3.js. The thing is I don´t know exactly how to do it. Any suggestion?

`val inputTable = sqlContext.jsonFile(inputDirectory).cache()`
`inputTable.registerTempTable("inputTable")`

```
val languages = sqlContext.sql("""
        SELECT 
            user.lang, 
            COUNT(*) as cnt
        FROM tweetTable 
        GROUP BY user.lang
        ORDER BY cnt DESC 
        LIMIT 15""")
languages.rdd.saveAsTextFile(outputDirectory + "/lang")
languages.collect.foreach(println)
```

I don´t mind if I save my data into a .csv file but I don´t know exactly how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174443/how-to-save-a-spark-dataframe-as-csv-on-disk/33174577#33174577

Answer (score 4):

It is just

```
val languagesDF: DataFrame = sqlContext.sql("<YOUR_QUERY>")
languagesDF.write.json("your.json")
```

You do not need to go back to a `RDD`.

Still, take care, that your JSON will be split into multiple parts.
If that is not your intention, read

- [Save a large Spark Dataframe as a single json file in S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908892/save-a-large-spark-dataframe-as-a-single-json-file-in-s3) and
- [Write single CSV file using spark-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674530/write-single-csv-file-using-spark-csv) (here for CSV but can easily be adapted to JSON)

on how to circumvent this (if really required). The main point is in using `repartition` or `coalesce`.

Comment: By any chance, do you know if it is possible to avoid the hadoopish format and store data to a file under a s3 key name of my choice instead of the directory with _SUCCES and part-* ?